# Call php function on a link

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have the following code but why does the function execute without pressing the link or meeting the if statement.

```
if($_SESSION['log'] == true)
{
   echo "<a href="'. function() .'"">LINK</a>;
}
else
{
 .......
}
```

Comment: with out giving a comment please dont give downvote.How he can correct his mistake without saying anything

Comment: your quotes are messed up

Comment: @Al. You are worried about quotes?

Comment: Read about the differences between server side and client side script script.

Comment: @Mr. Alien lol, well that was the first thing I saw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not call it like this.

What you can do is set link `href` to same page and pass some `get params` to that `link` and when that `get params isset` then `call` that `function`.

**Example**

```
<a href="same.php?action=callfunction">Click</a>
```

and code for calling function is as below.

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'callfunction'){
    //call function here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does the function execute without pressing the link

PHP deals in text (usually). It is the browser that deals in HTML. You are dealing with a string consisting of a string literal concatenated to the return value of a function call concatenated to another string literal (or you would be if your quotes weren't broken and causing a syntax error).

If you want the function to only fire when a link is clicked, then set the `href` attribute to the URL of a script which contains `function()`.

> or meeting the if statement.

That won't happen. The function appears inside the body of the `if` statement, so it won't fire unless the `if` is true.

Comment: This statement will bounce over his head `You are dealing with a string consisting of a string literal concatenated to the return value of a function call concatenated to another string literal`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language.  You can't trigger a function call in PHP from a link clicked in a browser in that way.

You would need to construct a URL with all the required parameters in the query string and pass that back to the PHP script in order for PHP to do something with the information

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery approach

like
$.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=1",
      success: function(result){
         alert(result);
      }
   }

in php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo "The id is ".id;
```

You'll get php function output in result from $.ajax success state.